# Shell script to browse one or more directories passed as parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I made this script that should receive one or more parameter, and those parameter are all directories, and it has to browse those directories (one by one) and do some operations.
The operations work fine if the parameter is `1` (only one directory), 
How should I modify my script to make it works if more than `1` parameter is passed
Example if I want it to do the same operations in `2` or `3` directories at the same time?
Thanks

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $1
for file in ./* # */
do    
  if [[ -d $file ]]
  then
    ext=dir
  else
    ext="${file##*.}"
  fi
  mv "${file}" "${file}.$ext"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using bash use bash shebang (#! /bin/bash).
Then use

```
#! /bin/bash

for d in "$@"
do
   echo "Do something with $d"
done
```

to iterate over the command line arguments (dirs in your case)

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for dir in "$@"; do                     
  for file in "$dir"/*; do
    echo "Doing something with '$file'"
  done
done
```